# Steady state capacitor voltage

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

[image]

This circuit is in steady-state. The open-circuit represents the capacitors in steady state.

Why is there voltage across Vc1? and no voltage across Vc2?

Comment: do you notice any other components across C2?

Comment: @Neil_UK wouldn't the voltage across R4 = to Vc2?

Comment: good observation. What is the steady state voltage across R4? And why?

Comment: It would be 30V. The voltage will be similar to the voltage across the 6ohms resistor. For that reason shouldn't the Vc2 be 30V as well? @Neil_UK Thanks alot

Comment: Where does the current come from that produces a voltage across R4? How does it get from the 40 V source?

Comment: Am I right to say that the current doesn't flow through the R4 resistor due to the open circuit at Vc1? @Neil_UK

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the steady state, no current flows through a capacitor.

Comment: @Neil_UK . Why does a voltage appear across Vc1, since it is an open circuit too during steady state? Shouldn't Vc1 be 0V too?

Comment: An open circuit can have any voltage across it, but no current through it. Now consider your voltage source and the loop C1 and R4, will they impress a voltage across C1?